# layout with before and after margins with equalToSystemSpacingAfter

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I’m trying to change some layouts I have to a number-less layout.
This is what I have for a segmented bar that should be inside a container view with something like this `| - margin - segmented - margin -|`

```
segmentedControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: margins.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 1),
segmentedControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: margins.trailingAnchor, multiplier: 1),
```

I know that the second line doesn’t make any sense, but I don’t see any equalToSystemSpacingBEFORE  just after, and I’m not sure how to do it without having to rely only on layout propagation.

Basically, the leadingAchor works fine with this code, but the trailingAnchor (as the method name implies) adds the margin AFTER the trailing anchor, which is not what I want.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can constrain the trailingAnchor of your "container" view relative to the trailingAnchor of your segmented control.

Here's a quick example which I *believe* gives you the layout you want:

```
class SysSpacingViewController: UIViewController {

    let seg: UISegmentedControl = {
        let v = UISegmentedControl(items: ["A", "B", "C"])
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let cView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow

        cView.addSubview(seg)
        view.addSubview(cView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let m = cView.layoutMarginsGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            cView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            cView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            cView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            cView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70.0),

            seg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: m.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            m.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: seg.trailingAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),

            seg.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.centerYAnchor),

        ])

    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: that's it,
This worked:

            segmentedControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 1),

            margins.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: segmentedControl.trailingAnchor, multiplier: 1),

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:

```
segmentedControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
segmentedControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
```

Please change the name of `containerView` and `constants` accordingly.

Comment: I know I can use the numbers, but the reason of doing what I'm doing is that I want a number-less layout. I know it can be done, it works for the leadingAnchor but I don't understand how it's supposed to work for the trailingAnchor